# Arrange BBpress replies in reverse order

Tags: bbpress

I want to Sort topic replies in descending order for all bbPress Topics to show the last reply in first postion.
There is an old plugin that doesn't work anymore:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress-sort-topic-replies
Is there any code to add it in theme's function to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the snippet to reverse replies order for the single topic:

```
add_filter('bbp_before_has_replies_parse_args', 'dev4press__change_replies_order');
function dev4press__change_replies_order($r) {
  $r['order'] = 'DESC';
  return $r;
}
```